# Not able to set ENV LUA_PATH No such file or directory

Tags: lua, environment-variables

I am working on open source LUA project. It has some modules and submodules. I am trying to set LUA_PATH env. But it always fails with error.

```
bash: ./user_modules/shared_testcases/?.lua: No such file or directory
```

Command I used is:

```
set LUA_PATH /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;./user_modules/shared_testcases/?.lua
```

Comment: Not really a question about Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the path:

```
set LUA_PATH '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;./user_modules/shared_testcases/?.lua'
```

Otherwise, as you have seen, the shell tries to expand the `?`
in the path.